# How can I clean up this code so that it isn't as long and does not involve much copying and pasting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is for a hangman game and it works perfectly.It, however, is quite messy and long because I had to copy and paste a lot of the code over and over again. It works but is not the most functional way of doing this. How can I clean up this code to not have to copy and paste over and over again? I already tried using a for loop and a while loop but that just messed up the game and the game then didn't work properly. How can I improve this code?

```
import random

def getWord():
    dictionary_file=open("dictionary.txt","r")
    lines=dictionary_file.readlines()
    words=[]
    for i in range(0,len(lines)-1):
        x=lines[i]
        z=len(x)
        a=x[:z-1]
        words.append(a)
    words.append(lines[i+1])
    game_word=random.choice(words)
    dictionary_file.close()
    return(game_word)

def display(game_word):
    for i in range(len(game_word)):
        print('_ ', end='')
    print()

def play(game_word):
    n = len(game_word)
    word = list("_"*n)

    guess1 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess1.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if guess1 in game_word[j]:
                word[j] = guess1 + " "
            else:
                word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))

    guess2 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess2.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess2 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess2 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess3 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess3.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess3 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess3 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess4 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess4.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess4 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess4 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess5 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess5.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess5 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess5 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return
        return

    guess6 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess6.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess6 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess6 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess7 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess7.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess7 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess7 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess8 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess8.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess8 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess8 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess9 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess9.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess9 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess9 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess10 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess10.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess10 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess10 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess11 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess11.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess11 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess11 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess12 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess12.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess12 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess12 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess13 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess13.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess13 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess13 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess14 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess14.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess14 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess14 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    guess15 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess15.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess15 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess15 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return

    print("YOU LOSE")
    print('Word was '+ game_word)

game_word = getWord()
display(game_word)
play(game_word)
```

Comment: Your question seems ok for Stack Overflow, but, just for your information, with a full program functioning as you posted, you can also consider posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (for similar future questions)

Comment: Try to identify the operation you repeat over and over and wrap the entire block in a for loop. In particular notice that you do not need to differentiate by guess1 and guess2, so in your for loop you can just refer to it as a general guess variable

Comment: Good for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

def getWord():
    dictionary_file=open("dictionary.txt","r")
    lines=dictionary_file.readlines()
    words=[]
    for i in range(0,len(lines)-1):
        x=lines[i]
        z=len(x)
        a=x[:z-1]
        words.append(a)
    words.append(lines[i+1])
    solution_word=random.choice(words)
    dictionary_file.close()
    return(solution_word)

def print_in_game(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        print(word[i], end=' ')
    print()

def play(solution_word):
    n = len(solution_word)
    word = list("_"*n)
    print_in_game(word)
    for index in range(15):
        guess = input("Letter: ")
        if not guess.isalpha():
            print("try letters please")
            continue
        for character_index in range(n):
            if word[character_index] == '_':
                if guess == solution_word[character_index]:
                    word[character_index] = guess + " "
                else:
                    word[character_index] = "_"
        print_in_game(word)
        if '_' not in word:
            print("YOU WIN")
            return    

    print("YOU LOSE")
    print('Word was '+ solution_word)

solution_word = getWord()
play(solution_word)
```

I hope it helps. It still can be improved with better variable names, and maybe the play function can be split to smaller functions it still seems a little long.

Comment: I tested before posting, I will check again in a moment. probably I did somthing wrong while uploading it here

Comment: Relax, it's just the import line.

Answer (score 1):

## You need to use a loop.

And in your case, it will be very simple.

Obviously, as you noticed, your code is largely a repetition of the same (or very similar) instructions.

For instance :

```
    guess10 = input("Letter: ")
    if guess10.isalpha():
        for j in range(n):
            if word[j] == '_ ':
                if guess10 in game_word[j]:
                    word[j] = guess10 + " "
                else:
                    word[j] = "_ "
    print("".join(word))
    if '_ ' not in word:
        print("YOU WIN")
        return
```

Is an example of the "pattern" that is repeated. The only difference is the number `10` in the variable name, because that's the 10's time that this code is executed.

Look at the definition of the variable :
`guess10 = input("Letter: ")`

Then, look at where it is used : **only** in this small part. Not after, not before.

So, instead of using different variables, you can **reuse"" the same (let's say `guess`).

Then, you just need to repeat the same code 14 times (as in the original code).

So, you just need to wrap this part of code in a `for a in range(14):`, replace `guess10` by simply `guess`, and that will reduce the line of codes used a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [enumerate](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZgqH0o-7pAhVrkeAKHeYwADMQFjABegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.programiz.com%2Fpython-programming%2Fmethods%2Fbuilt-in%2Fenumerate&usg=AOvVaw0BH16aRc0u7rZv3K2pLAln) to tidy up the range part in the for-loop, and with enumerate, instead of keep using subscriptions to get a value from the list, simple use the second variable.

That means, `(i, lines[i])` turns into `(i, v)`.

#### Opening and closing a file is considered bad practice, and should be replaced with a context manager:

```
def getWord():
    with open("dictionary.txt","r") as dictionary_file: #  Context manager are a better practice
        lines=dictionary_file.readlines()
        words=[]
        for i,v in enumerate(lines): # Enumerate will allow you to use the index of an iteration along-side the corresponding value
            words.append(v[:len(v)-1])
        words.append(v)
        game_word=random.choice(words)
        return(game_word)
```